# Why does Save as "Rendered Image" change the raster styling?

Tags: qgis, raster, rendering

Rasters exported from QGIS (via Save As > Rendered Image) do not retain original styling.  See attached.  Any thought on how to prevent this error?  The top image is exported from QGIS as a .bmp, the bottom is a screen grab from tilemill.

[image: DesiredStyling]

[image: ReturnedStyling]

Comment: It seems the final answer to this problem, aside from image quality issue, was the fact that I was not creating a vrt.

Answer (score 1):

When you save your raster layer as `Rendered image` from QGIS, the saved image quality depends on your choosed profile parameters. Please, check your settings to find which of them alters your output quality:

[image]